# Software for defining rules for folder permissions and monitoring deviations

Tags: windows, security, file-permissions

Let's say a company has a large number of users, and each user has a home area.

On each share used for home area folders, I would like to define some rules saying who is supposed to have which permissions on the folder.

Then I would like to audit automatically, that this is actually the case and get some sort of report on deviations.

So a rule for \MegaServer\Home01 could be defined something like:

- Domain Admins - Full Control
- Backup Agent - Read
- [Home folder owner] - Full Control

I am talking about Windows platform and Windows servers, although I think it would most likely also work for *nix machines that expose Windows shares.

Does software like this exist?

I could roll my own basic version, but if something already exists, that is usually a better option.

I am aware of tools to make displaying permissions easier (AccessEnum, DumpSec), but that is not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Using a tool like SUBInACL http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23510 and/or PowerShell (Get-ACL; Set-ACL) would solve your problem while also allowing you to script it.